# Scraping webpage (with R) where all elements are placed inside an <app-root> tag

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to solve the RPA challenge (www.rpachallenge.com) using R and `Rselenium`.

I always use xpath to select elements/tags of an html page but I just can not extract anything from this one, not even using the classic `rvest::html_nodes`. I believe that the problem is that the html here is generated via javascript because all elements in the body are inside `<app-root>...</app-root>` tags (which google tells me is how Angular apps are written).

By inspecting the nodesets you can see the different structure of the scraped page with the app-root tag but nothing in it. Any idea how to access the tags in this page?

```
# You can try it yourselves by running this chunk
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url <- "http://www.rpachallenge.com"
rpa <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  View
```

Comment: Yes. Javascript is involved here (no elements displayed if you  disable it in Chrome). You'll need to use RSelenium+Chrome headless (or PhantomJS) to access the elements of the page.

Comment: thanks, do you know which one of these https://hub.docker.com/u/selenium/ is the chrome headless ? I see a PhantomJS image but it says it's no longer supported

Comment: Just use https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome