# Scraping a web page in R without using RSelenium

Tags: r, screen-scraping, rvest, httr

I’m trying to do a simple scrap in the table in the following url:

https://www.bcb.gov.br/controleinflacao/historicometas

[Page Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdTNm.png)

By what i notice is that, When using `rvest::read_html` or `httr::GET` and when acessing the page source code i can't see anything related to the table, but when acessing google chrome developer tools, i can spot the table references in the elements tab.

Examble above is a simple code where i try to acess the content of the url and search of nodes that contain tables:

```
library( tidyverse )
library( rvest )

url <- “https://www.bcb.gov.br/controleinflacao/historicometas”

res <- url %>%
    read_html( ) %>%
    html_node( “table” )
```

this give me:

> {xml_nodeset (0)}

opening the source code of the url mentioned we can see:

view-source:https://www.bcb.gov.br/controleinflacao/historicometas

[Page Source Code print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl8KL.png)

[Page Developer Tool table print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoAVn.png)

By what i have searched the question is that the scripts avaible in source code load the table. I have seen some solutions that use RSelenium, but i would like to know if there is some solution where i can scrap this table without using Rselenium.

Some other related StackOverflow questions:

[Scraping webpage (with R) where all elements are placed inside an <app-root> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61418175/scraping-webpage-with-r-where-all-elements-are-placed-inside-an-app-root-tag)

[scraping table from a website result as empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66753132/scraping-table-from-a-website-result-as-empty)

(Last one is a python example)

Comment: Dynamically rendered content may appear elsewhere in the HTML or nowhere at all compared to if you inspect it in a browser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944527/reading-in-a-table-using-rvest/72944693#72944693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with dynamic sites, Network tab tends to be more useful than Inspector. And often you don't have to scroll through hundreds of requests or pages of minified javascript, you rather pick a search term from rendered page to identify the api endpoint that sent that piece of information.
In this case searching for "*Resolução CMN nº 2.615*" pointed to the correct call, most of the site content (in pure html) was delivered as json.

```r
library(tibble)
library(rvest)

historicometas <- jsonlite::read_json("https://www.bcb.gov.br/api/paginasite/sitebcb/controleinflacao/historicometas")
historicometas$conteudo %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_element("table") %>% 
  html_table()
#> # A tibble: 27 × 7
#>    Ano   Norma                             Data  Meta …¹ Taman…² Inter…³ Infla…⁴
#>    <chr> <chr>                             <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#>  1 1999  Resolução CMN nº 2.615 ​           30/6… 8       2       6-10    8,94   
#>  2 2000  Resolução CMN nº 2.615 ​           30/6… ​6       ​2       4-8     5,97   
#>  3 2001  Resolução CMN nº 2.615 ​           30/6… ​4       ​2       2-6     7,67   
#>  4 2002  Resolução CMN nº 2.744            28/6… 3,5     2       1,5-5,5 12,53  
#>  5 2003* Resolução CMN nº 2.842Resolução … 28/6… 3,254   22,5    1,25-5… 9,309,…
#>  6 2004* Resolução CMN nº 2.972Resolução … 27/6… 3,755,5 2,52,5  1,25-6… 7,60   
#>  7 2005  Resolução CMN nº 3.108            25/6… 4,5     2,5     2-7     5,69   
#>  8 2006  Resolução CMN nº 3.210            30/6… 4,5     ​2,0     2,5-6,5 3,14   
#>  9 2007  Resolução CMN nº 3.291            23/6… 4,5     ​2,0     2,5-6,5 4,46   
#> 10 2008  Resolução CMN nº 3.378            29/6… 4,5     ​2,0     2,5-6,5 5,90   
#> # … with 17 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​`Meta (%)`,
#> #   ²​`Tamanhodo intervalo +/- (p.p.)`, ³​`Intervalode tolerância (%)`,
#> #   ⁴​`Inflação efetiva(Variação do IPCA, %)`
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The following approach can also be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate("https://www.bcb.gov.br/controleinflacao/historicometas")

Sys.sleep(15)

doc <- IEApp$Document()
web_Obj_Table <- doc$querySelector('body > app-root > app-root > div > div > main > dynamic-comp > div > div:nth-child(8) > div')
text_Table <- web_Obj_Table$innerHtml()
read_html(text_Table) %>% html_table()

[[1]]
# A tibble: 27 x 7
   Ano   Norma                                        Data               `Meta (%)` Tamanhodo inter~1 Inter~2 Infla~3
   <chr> <chr>                                        <chr>              <chr>      <chr>             <chr>   <chr>  
 1 1999  Resolução CMN nº 2.615 ?                     ?30/6/1999?        8          2                 6-10    8,94   
 2 2000  Resolução CMN nº 2.615 ?                     ?30/6/1999?        ?6         ?2                4-8     5,97   
 3 2001  Resolução CMN nº 2.615 ?                     ?30/6/1999?        ?4         ?2                2-6     7,67   
 4 2002  Resolução CMN nº 2.744                       28/6/2000          3,5        2                 1,5-5,5 12,53  
 5 2003* Resolução CMN nº 2.842Resolução CMN nº 2.972 28/6/200127/6/2002 3,254      22,5              1,25-5~ 9,309,~
 6 2004* Resolução CMN nº 2.972Resolução CMN nº 3.108 27/6/200225/6/2003 3,755,5    2,52,5            1,25-6~ 7,60   
 7 2005  Resolução CMN nº 3.108                       25/6/2003          4,5        2,5               2-7     5,69   
 8 2006  Resolução CMN nº 3.210                       30/6/2004          4,5        ?2,0              2,5-6,5 3,14   
 9 2007  Resolução CMN nº 3.291                       23/6/2005          4,5        ?2,0              2,5-6,5 4,46   
10 2008  Resolução CMN nº 3.378                       29/6/2006          4,5        ?2,0              2,5-6,5 5,90   
# ... with 17 more rows, and abbreviated variable names 1: `Tamanhodo intervalo +/- (p.p.)`,
#   2: `Intervalode tolerância (%)`, 3: `Inflação efetiva(Variação do IPCA, %)`
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(pagedown)
library(tabulizer)

chrome_print("https://www.bcb.gov.br/controleinflacao/historicometas", output = "D:/table_PDF.pdf")
text_Tables <- extract_tables("D:/table_PDF.pdf")

[[1]]
      [,1]    [,2] [,3]                                               
 [1,] ""      ""   ""                                                 
 [2,] " PDF" ""   "2022 - Carta aberta"                              
 [3,] ""      ""   "2021 - <https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/controlein"
 [4,] " PDF" ""   "Carta"                                            
 [5,] ""      ""   "aberta"                                           
 [6,] ""      ""   ""                                                 
 [7,] " PDF" ""   "2017 - Carta Aberta"                              
 [8,] ""      ""   ""                                                 
 [9,] " PDF" ""   "2015 - Carta Aberta"                              
      [,4]                                                                      
 [1,] "<https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/controlein acao/controlein"              
 [2,] ""                                                                        
 [3,] "acao/controlein acao_docs/carta_aberta/OF_CIO_823_2022_BCB_SECRE_01.pdf>"
 [4,] ""                                                                        
 [5,] ""                                                                        
 [6,] "<https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/controlein acao/controlein"              
 [7,] ""                                                                        
 [8,] "<https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/controlein acao/controlein"              
 [9,] ""                                                                        
      [,5]                                   
 [1,] "acao_docs/carta_aberta/carta2022.pdf>"
 [2,] ""                                     
 [3,] ""                                     
 [4,] ""                                     
 [5,] ""                                     
 [6,] "acao_docs/carta_aberta/carta2017.pdf>"
 [7,] ""                                     
 [8,] "acao_docs/carta_aberta/carta2015.pdf>"
 [9,] ""                                     

[[2]]
      [,1]    [,2] [,3]                                               
 [1,] ""      ""   ""                                                 
 [2,] " PDF" ""   "2022 - Carta aberta"                              
 [3,] ""      ""   "2021 - <https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/controlein"
 [4,] " PDF" ""   "Carta"                                            
 [5,] ""      ""   "aberta"                                           
 [6,] ""      ""   ""                                                 
 [7,] " PDF" ""   "2017 - Carta Aberta"                              
 [8,] ""      ""   ""                                                 
 [9,] " PDF" ""   "2015 - Carta Aberta"                              
[10,] ""      ""   ""                                                 
[11,] ""      ""   ""                                                 
[12,] "Ano"   ""   "Norma"                                            
[13,] "1999"  ""   ""                                                 
[14,] "2000"  ""   "Resolução CMN no 2.615"                           
[15,] ""      ""   ""                                                 
[16,] "2001"  ""   ""                                                 
[17,] "2002"  ""   "Resolução CMN no 2.744"                           
[18,] "2003*" ""   "Resolução CMN no 2.842"                           
[19,] ""      ""   "Resolução CMN no 2.972"                           
[20,] "2004*" ""   "Resolução CMN no 2.972"                           
[21,] ""      ""   "Resolução CMN no 3.108"                           
[22,] "2005"  ""   "Resolução CMN no 3.108"                           
[23,] "2006"  ""   "Resolução CMN no 3.210"                           
[24,] "2007"  ""   "Resolução CMN no 3.291"                           
[25,] "2008"  ""   "Resolução CMN no 3.378"                           
      [,4]                                                                    
 [1,] "<https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/controlein acao/controlein"            
 [2,] ""                                                                      
 [3,] "acao/controlein acao_docs/carta_aberta/OF_CIO_823_2022_BCB_SECRE_01.pd"
 [4,] ""                                                                      
 [5,] ""                                                                      
 [6,] "<https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/controlein acao/controlein"            
 [7,] ""                                                                      
 [8,] "<https://www.bcb.gov.br/content/controlein acao/controlein"            
 [9,] ""                                                                      
[10,] "Mais"                                                                  
[11,] "Tamanho Intervalo"                                                     
[12,] "Data Meta (%) do intervalo +/- (p.p.) de tolerância (%)"               
[13,] "8 2"                                                                   
[14,] "30/6/1999  6  2"                                                       
[15,] ""                                                                      
[16,] "4  2"                                                                  
[17,] "28/6/2000 3,5 2 1,5-5,5"                                               
[18,] "28/6/2001 3,25 2 1,25-5,25"                                            
[19,] "27/6/2002 4 2,5 1,5-6,5"                                               
[20,] "27/6/2002 3,75 2,5 1,25-6,25"                                          
[21,] "25/6/2003 5,5 2,5"                                                     
[22,] "25/6/2003 4,5 2,5"                                                     
[23,] "30/6/2004 4,5  2,0 2,5-6,5"                                            
[24,] "23/6/2005 4,5 2,0 2,5-6,5"                                             
[25,] "29/6/2006 4,5 2,0 2,5-6,5"                                             
      [,5]                                   
 [1,] "acao_docs/carta_aberta/carta2022.pdf>"
 [2,] ""                                     
 [3,] ""                                     
 [4,] ""                                     
 [5,] ""                                     
 [6,] "acao_docs/carta_aberta/carta2017.pdf>"
 [7,] ""                                     
 [8,] "acao_docs/carta_aberta/carta2015.pdf>"
 [9,] ""                                     
[10,] ""                                     
[11,] "In ação efetiva"                      
[12,] "(Variação do IPCA, %)"                
[13,] "6-10 8,94"                            
[14,] "4-8 5,97"                             
[15,] ""                                     
[16,] "2-6 7,67"                             
[17,] "12,53"                                
[18,] "9,30"                                 
[19,] "9,30"                                 
[20,] "7,60"                                 
[21,] "3-8"                                  
[22,] "2-7 5,69"                             
[23,] "3,14"                                 
[24,] "4,46"                                 
[25,] "5,90"                                 

[[3]]
      [,1]   [,2]                     [,3]        [,4]       [,5]                              
 [1,] "Ano"  "Norma"                  "Data"      "Meta (%)" "Tamanho\rdo intervalo +/- (p.p.)"
 [2,] "2009" "Resolução CMN no 3.463" "26/6/2007" "4,5"      "2,0"                             
 [3,] "2010" "Resolução CMN no 3.584" "01/7/2008" "4,5"      "2,0"                             
 [4,] "2011" "Resolução CMN no 3.748" "30/6/2009" "4,5"      "2,0"                             
 [5,] "2012" "Resolução CMN no 3.880" "22/6/2010" "4,5"      "2,0"                             
 [6,] "2013" "Resolução CMN no 3.991" "30/6/2011" "4,5"      "2,0"                             
 [7,] "2014" "Resolução CMN no 4.095" "28/6/2012" "4,5"      "2,0"                             
 [8,] "2015" "Resolução CMN no 4.237" "28/6/2013" "4,5"      "2,0"                             
 [9,] "2016" "Resolução CMN no 4.345" "25/6/2014" "4,5"      "2,0"                             
[10,] "2017" "Resolução CMN no 4.419" "25/6/2015" "4,5"      "1,5"                             
[11,] "2018" "Resolução CMN no 4.499" "30/6/2016" "4,5"      "1,5"                             
[12,] "2019" "Resolução CMN no 4.582" "29/6/2017" "4,25"     "1,50"                            
[13,] "2020" "Resolução CMN no 4.582" "29/6/2017" "4,00"     "1,50"                            
[14,] "2021" "Resolução CMN no 4.671" "26/6/2018" "3,75"     "1,50"                            
[15,] "2022" "Resolução CMN no 4.724" "27/6/2019" "3,50"     "1,50"                            
[16,] "2023" "Resolução CMN no 4.831" "25/6/2020" "3,25"     "1,50"                            
[17,] "2024" "Resolução CMN no 4.918" "24/6/2021" "3,00"     "1,50"                            
[18,] "2025" "Resolução CMN no 5.018" "23/6/2022" "3,00"     "1,50"                            
      [,6]                           [,7]                                   
 [1,] "Intervalo\rde tolerância (%)" "Inação efetiva\r(Variação do IPCA, %)"
 [2,] "2,5-6,5"                      "4,31"                                 
 [3,] "2,5-6,5"                      "5,91"                                 
 [4,] "2,5-6,5"                      "6,50"                                 
 [5,] "2,5-6,5"                      "5,84"                                 
 [6,] "2,5-6,5"                      "5,91"                                 
 [7,] "2,5-6,5"                      "6,41"                                 
 [8,] "2,5-6,5"                      "10,67"                                
 [9,] "2,5-6,5"                      "6,29"                                 
[10,] "3,0-6,0"                      "2,95"                                 
[11,] "3,0-6,0"                      "3,75"                                 
[12,] "2,75-5,75"                    "4,31"                                 
[13,] "2,50-5,50"                    "4,52"                                 
[14,] "2,25-5,25"                    "10,06"                                
[15,] "2,00-5,00"                    "5,79"                                 
[16,] "1,75-4,75"                    ""                                     
[17,] "1,50-4,50"                    ""                                     
[18,] "1,50-4,50"                    ""
```